# How to use the data in cloud storage to do an alert function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alert

I am trying to use the cloud function to read the data that save in the bigquery. How should I use it and do an alert(email) to the user

Comment: I'd suggest to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Said that, what have you tried or investigated so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use cloud storage Trigger to run cloud function when the file is uploaded to the bucket, process file and store it into bigquery, use pubsub client in same cloud function to send message to the topic, use subscriber (custom application to send an email, notifications ) This is one way

Comment: At first, the data sent by the sensor has already decode into a few types of data and store in the big query. Now I want to use it to check whether that the specific data is lower or higher than the threshold value. When the real-time data is already lower or higher than the threshold value then send an alert(email) to the user

Is there any coding that may take the specific data from big query and make an alert when the data have already reached the threshold value?

Comment: You need to create a log-based custom matrix when data is inserted ( you have a sensor then you can make pub/sub logging ) and based on that matrix you can set up an alert policy with threshold condition, hope this will help you

Comment: How can I custom a matrix with the data in the big query?